# Wordpress get current page name or id within ajax request callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I need to get current page id or name from `ajax` request callback. Initially at loading a page i made an `ajax` request. In its callback method i need to get the current page id or name. I used following code for `ajax` request.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: my_site.home_url + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {
            action: "notes_select_page"
        },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (Response) {
            if (Response == "OK") {
                Notes.renderBoardList();
            } else {

            }
        },
        async: true
    });
```

I took the request from `action` hook.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_notes_select_page', 'Notes::select_page');add_action('wp_ajax_optimal_notes_select_page', 'Notes::select_page');
```

And the callback i used several code but doesn't work. Try 1.

```
public static function select_page(){
    global $pagename;
    die($pagename);
}
```

Try 2

```
public static function select_page(){
    global $wp_query;
    $pagename = get_query_var( 'pagename' );
    if ( !$pagename) {
        $post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $pagename = $post->post_name;
    }
    die($pagename);
}
```

Try 3

```
public static function select_page(){
    global $post;
    die($post->ID);
}
```

But unfortunately any of them doesn't work to get current page `ID` or `name`. Callback is working fine with other values.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you pass the page id through Ajax in data?

Comment: Would you please elaborate?

Comment: I mean you can pass the current post id as a parameter like you did action action: "notes_select_page", post-id:current_post_id

Comment: But the `ajax` call is in a `js` file.

Answer (score 3):

```
function get_current_page_id() {
    var page_body = $('body.page');

    var id = 0;

    if(page_body) {
        var classList = page_body.attr('class').split(/\s+/);

        $.each(classList, function(index, item) {
            if (item.indexOf('page-id') >= 0) {
                var item_arr = item.split('-');
                id =  item_arr[item_arr.length -1];
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    return id;
}
```

You don't need ajax for this.
Add this function to your code.
You can now get the page id by using:

```
var id = get_current_page_id();
```

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the post details you have to send the data yourself

```
data:{
    action: "notes_select_page",
    post_id: current_post_id, //current_post_id should either parsed from DOM or you can write your ajax in PHP file
}
```

You can either use a hidden box for current post id and get in the Js file using class or id or write the ajax in you php file itself.

Then you can retrieve via POST

```
public static function select_page(){
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

}
```

Comment: Actually all html data are made by dynamically from `jquery`. I can not use php within `jquery`. Would you please tell me how can i get id by DOM parsing. Thanks.

Comment: do you use event listener like on lick to fire the ajax request?

Comment: no event listener. but when JQuery ready function is triggered.

Comment: So you should move your js code to php file because ajax hook won't pass back a $post object to your callback

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting post ID from the default WordPress post editing form, like so :

```
var post_ID = jQuery('[name="post_ID"]').val()*1;
```

Tje `*1` converts the ID into an integer, otherwise it's interpreted as a string.

Comment: Simple and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. First take page id  by    this function

either

```
    <div id="current_page_id"> <?php get_the_ID(); ?> </div>
```

or

```
      <body page-id="<?php get_the_ID(); ?>">
```

Now In jquery ajax take following

```
var page_id = $('current_page_id').html();
```

OR

```
var page_id = $('body').attr("page-id");


 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: my_site.home_url + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: {
        action: "pageid="+page_id,
    },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (Response) {
        if (Response == "OK") {
            Notes.renderBoardList();
        } else {

        }
    },
    async: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to solve the issue in Wordpress. Adding ajax code in `wp_footer` hook, where using php code current page id can be retrieved and pass as ajax value.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain alternatively by the hidden field the post/page id in the following manner. This code is inserted in the template file (and then the value will be send to your ajax action hook as indicated above):

```
    <?php
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="activepost" id="activepost" 
    value="'.get_the_ID().'" />'
    ;?>
```

Check out this for reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/